# WPF DependencyProperty OnPropertyChanged returns default value as NewValue if using DataTemplate on UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, dependency-properties

I have an application in which I set the content of a contentpresenter, dependent on the  datatype by a datatemplate (see MainWindow). The Datatemplate is a usercontrol, which is actually datatype specific. (The small example below is only for demonstration, but in my "real" application the user shall be able to switch between different data.)

The usercontrol (UserControl1) has a DependencyProperty which I assign a value (in my application this is actually a binding to a VM, just set it to a string in example for simplicity).
Setting the value is still working fine. However In my UserControl I need to react to changes of the DependencyProperty to change the view of my UserControl (or later on CustomControl). So I implemented a  `OnPropertyChangend` method.
When application starts `OnPropertyChanged` works as I expect it and I get the "correct" newvalue of my DependencyProperty. However, if I change my VM (i.e. my datatemplate changes) during runtime by clicking on a button, `OnPropertyChanged` returns the DependencyProperty's defaultvalue.
In my small example application, I can see that the value is set correctly, as the Textblock content changes to the correct value.
It only seems that `OnPropertyChanged` gets fired **before** my DependencyProperty's value gets the new value. So, it's not possible for me to react on the new value.

It is not really clear why this happens. Seems to have something to do with the order in which WPF resolves internal stuff?
Does anyone have a clue, how I can fix this behavior and get access to the current/last value when changing my VM and don't miss an update? As stated out before, I need to react on that value.

Maybe I am doing something totally stupid here. Is the approach I decided to use here a bad one? Are  DataTemplates the wrong approach to switch between two pairs? What would be a better approach then? However, I guess it won't be possible to avoid the DependencyProperty and the UserControl in my application.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<!--MainWindow.xaml -->
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ActiveVM}">
            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM1}">
                    <local:UserControl1 MyProperty="Test1"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM2}">
                    <local:UserControl1 MyProperty="Test2"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentPresenter.Resources>    
        </ContentPresenter>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vmParent = new VMParent();
        DataContext = vmParent; 
        var vm1 = new VM1();
        var vm2 = new VM2();
    }
    VMParent vmParent;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vmParent.ChangeActiveVM();
    }

}
```

UserControl1.xaml

```
<!--UserControl1.xaml -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl1}}}"/>
```

UserControl1.cs

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata("DefaultString", OnMyPropertyChangend));

    private static void OnMyPropertyChangend(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == "DefaultString")
        {
            ;
            //xxxxxx
            //unexpectedly i get stuck here
            //Would expect/need NewValue to be Text1/Text2 to react to it
            //xxxxxx
        }
    }
}
```

VMParent

```
class VMParent : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public VMParent()
    {
        vm1 = new VM1();
        vm2 = new VM2();
        ActiveVM = vm1;

    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    VM1 vm1;
    VM2 vm2;

    public object ActiveVM 
    {
        get => m_activeVM;
        set { m_activeVM = value; OnPropertyChanged("ActiveVM"); }
    }
    private object m_activeVM;

    protected internal void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }

    public void ChangeActiveVM()
    {
        if (ActiveVM is VM1)
            ActiveVM = vm2;
        else
            ActiveVM = vm1;
    }
}
```

VMs are only used to apply Datatemplate

```
class VM1
{
}

class VM2
{
}
```

Comment: Be aware that by switching between the DataTemplates new instances of the UserControl will be created. There will never be a change of MyProperty from "Test1" to "Test2" (and back) in a single UserControl1 instance when ChangeActiveVM is called. In case this was your expectation, not sure...

Comment: OnMyPropertyChanged is called once with the default property value, and another time with either "Test1"  or "Test2", but as said, always on a new instance of the control. To get a better picture of what happens, add `Debug.WriteLine(e.NewValue);` to OnMyPropertyChanged, and `Loaded += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Loaded");` and `Unloaded += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine("Unloaded");` to the UserControl1 constructor, and observe the Output Window in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And sorry for my stupidity. I've been sitting too long searching for my bug, so when I saw that the condition inside ´OnMyPropertyChanged ´ got hit, I did not realize that the method was called twice.
That behavior is great for me, even if I was not aware that new instance is created, but makes totally sense.
I was so focussed on the DataTemplate stuff, that I did miss, that my error was on the DependencyProperty. The behavior was caused by binded variable not matching type of the dependencyproperty. Unfortunately this does not generate any binding error, in output window...